# Is there any method to detect a scratch on a line of text?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

Right now I have a label with many lines of text as below. I want to find a way to detect if there are any scratch in a line (the first and the last line). Any recommendation, thanks.

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. If you already have some setup that reads the text, you should show some code. If you are looking for a tool that can handle this for you, then that is off topic - we don't do such recommendations here.

Comment: first you'd need to establish a coordinate frame on the label, so it's upright. *then* you'd just scan pixel rows and see if there's any ink at all. if not, that printer's pixel was broken. -- *how* to rectify the picture is the bigger issue. you could find a horizontal line from associating glyphs into lines of text. or you could try to detect the barcode and work from that. -- your picture isn't just a perspective view. it's warped additionally. good luck getting that flattened. _not_ trivial.

Comment: if you're *only* looking to OCR the label, you should instead train OCR to *tolerate* those defects.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption the text lines are aligned horizontally.

- Threshold the black text to get a mask.
- Count the black pixel in each row of the image. This gives you a vector with the number of rows.
- In this vector, You should see a pattern of small and high values which
  represent empty  and filled lines.
- Scratches are small values between two high values.

Another way is to fit a line using Hough transform:
https://learnopencv.com/hough-transform-with-opencv-c-python/